# How can I implement a TextWriter in order to append a timestamp to each line writen to the console?

Tags: c#, windows

My apologies if this has already been answered, I've tried my best to look.

I have a library that writes some information to the console.  In the application that uses the library, I'd like to redirect that output to a control as well as a log file, while writing a timestamp at the beginning of each line.  This is what my class looks like:

```
class TextBoxStreamWriter : TextWriter
{
    TextBox _output;
    FileStream _stream;
    StreamWriter _writer;

    // constructor
    public TextBoxStreamWriter(TextBox output)
    {
        _output = output;

        _stream = new FileStream(@"C:\example.log", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        _writer = new StreamWriter(_stream);
        _writer.AutoFlush = true;
    }

    // override methods
    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        base.Write(value);
        _output.AppendText(value.ToString());
        _writer.Write(value);
    }
    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        base.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("[yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss]\t") + value);
    }
```

This seems to work fine as long as you're using `Console.WriteLine()` of course.  But we I try to direct the output of an XMLWriter to the console, this bypasses `Console.WriteLine()`, and thereby starts printing lines without the timestamp.  One example could be this:

```
    protected void WriteXMLToConsole(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
    {
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xmlDocument.WriteContentTo(writer);
        writer.Flush();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does your code that instantiates `TextBoxStreamWriter` look like?

Comment: You might want to look into libraries like NLog or log4Net instead of writing your own logger.  They are very easy to use, are highly performant (when you turn off logging), are super easy to configure, support the type of logger teeing you're wanting to do, and support automatically logging to formats that are readable by existing tools.  You could also plug it in to your textbox and have most of this problem automatically solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the xmlDoc is recieved as a single string containing NewLine.
Try reading the xmlDoc as a plain text-file, and sendt that text to console line-by-line